# Infinite while loop even though the condition does not satisfy it C++

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

When the while condition is not satisfied (validity is false) the first time, the code runs normally and prints "Valid".

However when the while condition is satisfied (validity is true) and then it becomes not satisfied, it doesn't exit the loop. It turns into an infinite loop, printing "Not valid, please try again." and "Enter card number" over and over again.

I really have no clue what's wrong with my code.

Thank you in advance.

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//count the number of digits
int numdig(int digits)
{
    int count = 0;
    while (digits != 0)
    {
        digits = digits / 10;
        ++count;
    }
    return count;
}
//valid length or not
bool validity(int len){
    bool notValid;
    if(len<14 or len>16){
        notValid = 1;
    }
    else{
        notValid = 0;
    }
    return notValid;
}


int main()
{
    int digits;
    cout<<"Enter CN: ";
    cin>>digits;
    cout<<numdig(digits)<< endl;
    cout<<validity(numdig(digits))<<endl;

    while(validity(numdig(digits))){
        cout<<"Not valid, please try again."<<endl;
        cout<<"Enter card number "<<endl;
        cin>>digits;
        validity(numdig(digits));
    }

    cout<<"Valid";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int digits` usually holds no more than 10 digits (up to 2,147,483,647). You need to use `long long` for that extra length.

Comment: You can reduce your `validity()` method to `{ return len >= 14 && len <= 16; }` Don't write eight lines of code where one will do. And when you call it, don't just throw away the result. In fact you don't need the second call at all.